# Returning multiple scopes of response in REST service

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, dto

I am creating Spring REST web service which returns data depending on user's rights and one input as query param (some string property). User's rights are encoded in database of web service.

Lets's say we have three types of users. First has right of degree A, second B and third C. Every json answer is subset (defined by users rights) of same data (joined tables). So, first user can see fields F1...F3, second F1...F6 and third F1...F7. Client is not aware of his rights. How would you model such situation. Should I create one DTO and return it by filling "not authorized" columns with nulls or something else or create multiple models and put them in some json wrapper, but then user would not be aware of return type and will have to null-check every field and that wouldn't really be a "contract".

Comment: You should have some type of table that defines what "degree A" is allowed to view

Comment: I do have table that defines which user has which rights. But client doesn't have access to database, of course. So, main problem is that my service can return DTO1, DTO2 and DTO3 and serialize it as json. I see three options. First is to take "largest" scope and fill "not authorized fields" with nulls (that can be deceiving) or something else or create some wrapper which contains all these models (DTO1, DTO2, DTO3) and return that wrapper. But then, user will have to null-check every parsed field.

Comment: Consider using Jackson views and/or filters.  This allows a single model, but various views/filters of the model.  For security purposes, attributes which the user does not have access should not be in the response at all, even if with a null value, since that would exposes parts of the model the user cannot access (even though there is no value).